# Python: Define own function called "randomcall"

Tags: python, function, for-loop, random, phonebook

so i am stuck on a certain problem I have to solve and was wondering if you guys could help me in my situation (i am really new to python and programming by itself). So the task i got is, to define a own new function to pick out of a Dictionary called "phonebook" random people and print out to pretend calling them. Something like "randomcall(phonebook,10)  and then it prints: Calling Peter at 1800650, and 9 others.

```
def randomcall(phonebook, number):
    import random
    
    for name in range(phonebook):
        name = random.choice(list(phonebook))
        phonebook = phonebook[name]
        print(f"Let's call {name} with {phonebook}")

phonebook = {"martin": 12345, "anna": 65478, "klaus": 5468764, "hans": 748463, "peter": 84698416, "ulrich": 3416846546, "frank": 4789749, "lukas": 798469, "ferdinand": 68465131}

randomcall(phonebook, 3)

randomcall("", 5)
```

Comment: I think you mean `for i in range(number)` instead of `for name in range(phonebook)`, because `name` is used later on and there is no need to make it the iterating variable, and `phonebook` is the dictionary, not the # of people you are calling.

Comment: Also, what does `randomcall("", 5)` mean? Are you trying to call nobody there?

Comment: You are right, the randomcall("",5) is not necessary, it was a try to call a random person, but thats not how this works.

Comment: would the example `5` in `randomcall("",5)` mean on how many people to call?

Comment: yes it will @StackOffended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, except for several small mistakes:

1. As said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357501/python-define-own-function-called-randomcall#comment115546623_65357501) above, you cannot use `for name in range(phonebook)` because `phonebook` is not the integral number of times that you need to iterate. `number` is. Also the variable `name` is not referenced to in the iteration; it was assigned a new value. So it can be changed into another variable, like `i`, which is used more commonly in iteration.
2. The number of the person to call is, in your code, stored under the variable `phonebook`, which is the variable of the phonebook dictionary. It makes it impossible to access the actual phonebook again. Another variable, like `phone`, can be used there.

So the completed code should look like:

```py
def randomcall(phonebook, number):
    import random

    for name in range(number):
        name = random.choice(list(phonebook))
        phonebook = phonebook[name]
        print(f"Let's call {name} with {phonebook}")


phonebook = {"martin": 12345, "anna": 65478, "klaus": 5468764, "hans": 748463, "peter": 84698416, "ulrich": 3416846546, "frank": 4789749, "lukas": 798469, "ferdinand": 68465131}

randomcall(phonebook, 3)
```

Output:

```
Let's call anna with 65478
Let's call klaus with 5468764
Let's call hans with 748463
```

Also, as stated in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357501/python-define-own-function-called-randomcall#comment115546846_65357501), the line `randomcall("", 5)` is used to call a random person. Actually, the phonebook must be passed to the function as the `phonebook` parameter, and if `1` is passed to the `number` parameter, it generates 1 random call.

Answer (score 1):

You could this, `number` will be the range on how many people to call.

```
import random

def randomcall(phonebook,number):

    for _ in range(number):
        name = random.choice(list(phonebook.keys()))
        print(f'Lets call {name} with {phonebook[name]}')



phonebook = {"martin":12345,"anna":65478,"klaus":5468764,"hans":748463,"peter":84698416,"ulrich":3416846546,"frank":4789749,"lukas":798469,"ferdinand":68465131}

randomcall(phonebook,3)
```

**Output:**

```
Lets call lukas with 798469
Lets call peter with 84698416
Lets call klaus with 5468764
```